# <html:checkbox> and <s:checkbox> behaves differently

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, checkbox, struts2, struts1

I am migrating checkbox from Struts1 to Struts2.
So I changed the code from Struts1

```jsp
<html:checkbox style="border:0px" property="eDir" disabled="true"/>
```

to

```jsp
<s:checkbox theme="simple" style="border:0px" name="eDir" disabled="true"></s:checkbox>
```

but I don't get the checkbox as checked even if the value is `true`

Below are the html script of both

**Struts1 html:**

```jsp
<input type="checkbox" name="eDir2ColTrue" value="on" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" style="border:0px">
```

**Struts2 html:**

```jsp
<input type="checkbox" name="eDir2ColTrue" value="true" disabled="disabled" id="eDir2ColTrue" style="border:0px">
<input type="hidden" id="__checkbox_eDir2ColTrue" name="__checkbox_eDir2ColTrue" value="true" disabled="disabled">
```

The field is boolean .I am getting its value in action class as true from model object..but still its unchecked.

**Update:**

I tried this but its not compiling

```jsp
<s:checkbox theme="simple" style="border:0px" key="eDir" disabled="true" <s:if test='${eDir}' >checked="checked"</s:if>></s:checkbox>
```

**Update1:**

I tried this but there is no checked attribute so it is not checked despite its value being true

```jsp
<s:checkbox theme="simple" style="border:0px" key="eDir" disabled="true" value="%{#eDir}"></s:checkbox>
```

**Update2:**

When I print, i.e. `<c:out value="${eDir}"></c:out>`, I get the value as `true`
but the same I put it in the value attribute, it still doesn't have a checked attribute.

```jsp
<s:checkbox theme="simple" style="border:0px" key="eDir" disabled="true" value="${eDir}"></s:checkbox>
```

Comment: Are you trying out the this example http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckbox-checkbox-example/

Answer (score 1):

Struts2 `checkbox` tag behave differently than its analog in Struts1.

And, as you have mentioned Struts2 creates two `input` fields for a single checkbox - one for `checked` value, and other for unchecked value.

Then passing one of them that is checked. The default stack of interceptors include [`checkbox` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/checkbox-interceptor.html) that handles submitted values.

If you are using Struts2 checkbox and want to use field value to be not boolean then you should use `fieldValue` attribute.

```
<s:checkbox theme="simple" cssStyle="border:0px" name="eDir" disabled="true" fieldValue="on"/>
```

Comment: field Value is boolean,i get the value as true in html but still there is no checked attribute

Comment: It can't be boolean because `value="on"` is generated. The second is boolean because `value="true"`.

Comment: when i explicitly specify value="true", it checks the checkbox.but the same thing i do it with jstl i.e. value="${eDir}" it is unchecked and i when i print on jsp ${eDir} it gives me true.what can be the issue??

Comment: you can't do such things because Struts tags don't have JSTL functionality.